# How can I display immediately the new opened tab contents in BootstrapVue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabs, bootstrap-vue

Good morning,

my goal is the following:

**Each time a new tab is opened, it becomes 'active' and the browser displays its content**

- Problem: Each time a new tab is opened, the previously opened tab remains 'active'.

[Look at a trivial example of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqzCE.png)

In order to reproduce the problem:

1. Access the [BootstrapVue Playground](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tabs);
2. Scroll to the bottom of the page, in the section entitled 'Dynamic tabs + tabs-end slot' (present in the advanced examples section);
3. Double-click in the code area (to be able to modify it);
4. Paste the following code

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-card no-body>
      <b-tabs card>
        <!-- Render Tabs, supply a unique `key` to each tab -->
        <b-tab v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.id" :class="{active:tab.isActive}" :title="'Tab ' + tab.id">
          Tab contents {{ tab.id }}
          <b-button size="sm" variant="danger" class="float-right" @click="closeTab(tab.id)">
            Close tab
          </b-button>
        </b-tab>

        <!-- New Tab Button (Using tabs-end slot) -->
        <template v-slot:tabs-end>
          <b-nav-item role="presentation" @click.prevent="newTab" href="#"><b>+</b></b-nav-item>
        </template>

        <!-- Render this if no tabs -->
        <template v-slot:empty>
          <div class="text-center text-muted">
            There are no open tabs<br>
            Open a new tab using the <b>+</b> button above.
          </div>
        </template>
      </b-tabs>
    </b-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        tabs: [],
        tabCounter: 0,
        activeTab: {}
      }
    },
    methods: {
      closeTab(x) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.tabs.length; i++) {
          if (this.tabs[i].id === x) {
            this.tabs.splice(i, 1)
          }
        }
      },
      newTab() {
        const newTab = {
          id: this.tabCounter,
          isActive: true
        };
        this.tabCounter++;
        this.tabs.push(newTab);
        this.setActive(newTab);
      },
      setActive(tab) {
        tab.isActive = true;
        this.activeTab = tab;
        this.tabs.forEach((tab) => {
          if (tab.id !== this.activeTab.id) {
            tab.isActive = false;
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

5. Try adding new tabs by clicking on the '+' button in the rendering area, present at the beginning of the pasted code.

**What am I doing wrong ?**

Comment: I have tried to adapt the example shown in this [example fiddle with jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/gmsa/gfg30Lgv/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding the `active` prop to `<b-tab>`, this will make the newly created tab the active one.

```html
<b-tab active ...>
```

#### Example

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tabs: [],
      tabCounter: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    closeTab(x) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.tabs.length; i++) {
        if (this.tabs[i] === x) {
          this.tabs.splice(i, 1)
        }
      }
    },
    newTab() {
      this.tabs.push(this.tabCounter++)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.16.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.16.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-card no-body>
    <b-tabs card>
      <!-- Render Tabs, supply a unique `key` to each tab -->
      <b-tab v-for="i in tabs" :key="'dyn-tab-' + i" :title="'Tab ' + i" active>
        Tab contents {{ i }}
        <b-button size="sm" variant="danger" class="float-right" @click="closeTab(i)">
          Close tab
        </b-button>
      </b-tab>

      <!-- New Tab Button (Using tabs-end slot) -->
      <template v-slot:tabs-end>
        <b-nav-item role="presentation" @click.prevent="newTab" href="#"><b>+</b></b-nav-item>
      </template>

      <!-- Render this if no tabs -->
      <template v-slot:empty>
        <div class="text-center text-muted">
          There are no open tabs<br>
          Open a new tab using the <b>+</b> button above.
        </div>
      </template>
    </b-tabs>
  </b-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I've commented wrong. Thank you so much for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use b-tabs

1. Event: [changed](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tabs#comp-ref-b-tabs-events)
2. Property: [v-model](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tabs#comp-ref-b-tabs-props)

```
<b-tabs v-model="tabActive" @changed="onTabChanged">

data() {
  return {
    tabActive: 0,
    tabs:[],
  }

onTabChanged() {
  this.tabActive = this.tabs.length - 1;
},
```

Comment: but if u delete a tab, the last tab become active.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there MIchele Rosito,

the component b-tabs accepts a value, that value is the selected tab index (pass it via v-model)

below I have a simplified version of a working prototype that I think it does what you what.

But there is a catch, when adding a new tab this will be rendered by bootstap on the (virtual) DOM, and that will take some time, and we cannot select a tab that is not yet rendered.

The "solution" (a not so good bandage) is to give it a few milliseconds and only then change the "tabIndex" to give some time for the tab to render.

This is not the best solution for production but I think it can point you in the right direction.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-card no-body>
      <b-tabs card v-model="tabIndex">
        <!-- Render Tabs, supply a unique `key` to each tab -->
        <b-tab v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab.id" :class="{active:tab.isActive}" :title="'Tab ' + tab.id">
          Tab contents {{ tab.id }}
          <b-button size="sm" variant="danger" class="float-right" @click="closeTab(tab.id)">
            Close tab
          </b-button>
        </b-tab>

        <!-- New Tab Button (Using tabs-end slot) -->
        <template v-slot:tabs-end>
          <b-nav-item role="presentation" @click.prevent="newTab" href="#"><b>+</b></b-nav-item>
        </template>

        <!-- Render this if no tabs -->
        <template v-slot:empty>
          <div class="text-center text-muted">
            There are no open tabs<br>
            Open a new tab using the <b>+</b> button above.
          </div>
        </template>
      </b-tabs>
    </b-card>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        tabs: [],
        tabIndex: 0,
        tabCounter: 0,
        activeTab: {}
      }
    },
    methods: {
      closeTab(x) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.tabs.length; i++) {
          if (this.tabs[i].id === x) {
            this.tabs.splice(i, 1)
          }
        }
      },
      newTab() {
        const newTab = {
          id: this.tabCounter,
        };
        this.tabCounter++;
        this.$set(this, tabs, this.tabs.push(newTab));  
        setTimeout(() => { this.tabIndex = this.tabs.length;}, 100);      
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Was it helpful?

Comment: please don't use my "solution" use Hiws one :)

Comment: Yes @ Fabio Garcia, with this solution I can better understand the problem and think about it: it solves my problem. Now it is to be understood whether the second solution you propose is better in terms of performance.